# Get IIS version programmatically

Tags: c#, iis, version, servermanager

I want to access an IIS server programmatically in C# and I choose to use Microsoft.Web.Configuration.dll. Is there a way to get the current IIS version with this dll or another?

Answer (score 0):

```
Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_SOFTWARE"];
```